# Include calculated fields in Parse Objects queries

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm currently working on a Parse Server based API for a cooking social network, and espectially on a function retrieving recipes. I would like to allow this function to expose calculated fields, for example title field, which would pick up the right title string among several existing (titleFr, titleEn, titleEs, ...) upon language.
I understand from another contributions that I should work on Parse.Promise but I just can't find the hack : function response still only expose stored fields. Does anyone know ?

```
Parse.Cloud.define('getRecipes', function(request, response) {
    var lang = getLocale(request); // a homemaid function 
    var recipes = new Parse.Query("Recipe");
    recipes.find().then(function (recipes) {
        console.log("Successfully retrieved " + recipes.length + " recipes.");
        var recipe = recipes.map(function (recipe) {
            recipe.title = recipe.get("title" + lang);
            return recipe;
        });
        return Parse.Promise.when(recipe);
    }).then(function (results) {
        response.success(results);
    }).fail(function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `return recipes.map....` instead of `var recipe... return Parse.Promise.When(recipe);`

Since `recipe` isn't actually a promise, I don't believe it gets waited on the same way, here. Could be mistaken.

Also, FYI, you're missing a `response.error()` call in the event of a failed query.